# XPath query in a recursive DTD

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xpath-3.0

I'm using XPath 3.0 and I've the following problem.
I need to write a function that returns true/false, checking whether the names of the resources (files and folders) are such that all resources have a distinct pathname.

[image: This is my Document Type Definition]

I am able to retrieve the name of the ancestor nodes folders of a specific folder but then I cannot think of how to build a "path name" from that to then perform the comparison. Any idea?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-string-join should give you an idea to build a path of names.

Comment: I think I found the solution, thank you again and have a nice day! :)

Comment: @Pagli Then post your solution here to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following expression checks whether there are any duplicate file/folder names in any folder. That should be sufficient to check whether there are no duplicate path names.

```
//*[self::RootFolder|self::Folder][count(distinct-values(*/Name))!=count(File|Folder)]
```

Additional checks to make sure the path separator is not used in any file/folder names would be required.